# @Valid @CustomValidator inside a spring @Service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I used to validate my beans inside my spring `@RestController` like:

```
@PostMapping("/documents")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@Valid @RequestBody document: DocumentCreate) {
    return documentService.create(document)
}
```

Even it seems stupid, I would like now to validate my bean depending on a `DocumentCreate` boolean property like:

```
@PostMapping("/documents")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@RequestBody document: DocumentCreate) {
    return when {
        document.needValidation -> documentService.createWithValidation(document),
        else -> documentService.createWithoutValidation(document)
    }
}
```

I tried to move the `@Valid` annotation to the document `@Service` class but it does not trigger the validation. How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Comment: You can check if document needs validation or not in your custom validator (implementation of `ConstraintValidator`). If validation is no needed just return `true`, otherwise do your custom validation, return its result and always call `documentService.createWithoutValidation(document)` (you just did one validation) in your controller cause at this point your object is already validated. I can add some sample code if it's what you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who is wondering how to do it using annotation. Annotate your service class with spring's @Validated. Once done, it will fire the validation of the input bean in your service class method that is decorated with @Valid.

Comment: It does not solve my problem. The idea is to activate/deactivate validation based on a trigger (`document.needValidation` in my example). Of course `@Validated` could be used if you don't have `@RequestBody` annotation on your payload. You don't need to use it if you have `@RequestBody`: Optionally, automatic validation can be applied by annotating the argument with {`@code @Valid`}.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by instantiating a validator bean:

```
import javax.validation.Validator
...
@Autowired
lateinit var validator: Validator
```

and I use it in my create function:

```
@PostMapping("/documents")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@RequestBody document: DocumentCreate) {
    return when {
        document.needValidation -> {
            val errors = validator.validate(document)
            if (errors.isNotEmpty()) {
                throw ConstraintViolationException(errors)
            }
            documentService.create(document)
        }
        else -> documentService.create(document)
    }
}
```

I did not find a way to do it with annotations in the service layer.